# How to add an animation delay using Animate.css and ViewportChecker?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, viewport

I am trying to add a "delay" to different animated class elements on a particular web page using Daniel Eden's animate.css version 3.5.1 and jquery-viewport-checker version 1.8.7 by Dirk Groenen.

I tried to use setTimeout Function like ...

```
setTimeout(function () {
jQuery('.fadeinleft1').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInLeft',
    offset: 100
   });
}, 500
);
```

But that obviously affects the hidden class as well. I need just the animation delayed as it reaches viewport and I can delay each object accordingly. Been looking for sometime and just cannot find the answer yet.

Answer (score 17):

Go figure, as soon as I ask a question, I find a fix that involves only adding css. Do not need to touch the javascript. Very quick and easy way to achieve delayed animation when using animate.css and viewport-checker. You do it by adding a css class that uses "animation-delay."

Javascript:

```
jQuery('.fadeinleft').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInLeft',
    offset: 100
   });
```

Create the following animated delay css however you want and how many you want and you can use them globally on all animations:

```
.delay-1 {
animation-delay: .25s;
}
.delay-2 {
animation-delay: .5s;
}
.delay-3 {
animation-delay: .75s;
}
.delay-4 {
animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

Then all you need to do is add the classes to the animated elements as such:

```
<div class="col-md-4 fadeinleft">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="box-border-wht">
                <p>Title 1</p>
                <img src="/images/image1.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 fadeinleft delay-1">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="box-border-wht">
                <p>Title 2</p>
                <img src="/images/image2.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 fadeinleft delay-2">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="box-border-wht">
                <p>Title 3</p>
                <img src="/images/image3.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

That is it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you're using `viewportChecker()`, or any javascript/jQuery at all. The solution you posted is using jQuery to add the `hidden` css class to your element ([`hidden` has been replaced by `d-none`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) as of Bootstrap 4), but this is unnecessary as the `animated` class will automatically handle this for you. The goal of Animate.css is to provide efficient, seamless animations without superfluous javascript/jQuery code.

Because Animate.css uses the `animation(-name)` css property to animate elements, it therefore respects the `animation-delay` css property. Your solution should work even if you entirely remove the jQuery code (as explained above).